# jquery hide is hiding submenu content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to have a html document that holds a lot of content, kind of an online manuel. I want all the content to be viewable just by scrolling down the web page. I would also like to have a menu with a sub-menu of a list of sections on the web page the the user can click to quickly navigate through the webpage. I am currently seeing an issue were my jquery code is hiding everything below my list until I hover over the Menu. `

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simple jQuery Dropdown Menu | Finished Article</title>

<style type="text/css">

/*style the main menu*/
.myMenu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.myMenu li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif #111;
}

.myMenu li a:link, .myMenu li a:visited {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#09F;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    margin:0;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    color:#111;
}

.myMenu li a:hover {
    background-color:#0CF;  
}

/*style the sub menu*/
.myMenu li ul {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    margin:0;
    padding:10;
}

.myMenu li ul li {
    display:inline;
    float:none;
}

.myMenu li ul li a:link, .myMenu li ul li a:visited {
    background-color:#09F;
    width:200px;
}

.myMenu li ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#0CF;  
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#list,#list ul li,#list ul li a").hover(function(){
    $("#text").children().show();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.myMenu > li').bind('mouseover', openSubMenu);
        $('.myMenu > li').bind('mouseout', closeSubMenu);

        function openSubMenu() {
            $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');
        };

        function closeSubMenu() {
            $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'hidden');         
        };

});
</script>

</head>
 <body>
 <h1>Pps1:Pps1.Generic.G5</h1>
 <p><a href='#ProcDesc'>ProcedureDescription</a></p>
 <ul class="myMenu">
    <li id="list"><a href="#ProcDesc">Procedure Descriptions</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#Pps1BpTS.TSC'>Pps1BpTS.TSC</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Pps1ContCheck.TSC'>Pps1ContCheck.TSC</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Pps1ErrorText.TSC'>Pps1ErrorText.TSC</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Pps1Exit.TSC'>Pps1Exit.TSC</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Pps1ForceStandby.TSC'>Pps1ForceStandby.TSC</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Pps1Greet.TSC'>Pps1Greet.TSC</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Pps1HWGains.TSC'>Pps1HWGains.TSC</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Pps1Init.TSC'>Pps1Init.TSC</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Pps1LimitActionEStop.TSC'>Pps1LimitActionEStop.TSC</a></li>
        <ul>
    </li>
</ul>
 <h2>Module Description</h2>
 <p>AeroViroment Cycler Generic Module2.3.1, </p>
 <p></p>
 <p>Communication Type: CAN (MS) via CANNeo driver</p>
 <p>Supported Equipment: AV cyclers:AV900, ABC1000, ABC170, ABC150, and MT30</p>
 <p></p>
 <p>It is currently configured to handle Channel A or Channel B on the two channel Cyclers, this is controlled via numPps1Channel which can be set prior to boot up in the Pps1.ini file. This module was made to work as a Cycler Driver in a BcTS/BpTS application. </p>
 <p></p>
 <p>Revision History:</p>
 <p></p>
 <p>2009Jan5, csierra@aanddtech.com, Initial Release for POC testing2.3.2  </p>
 <p>2010Feb5, jdajos@aanddtech.com, fixed init error if test is stopped early and restarted from the beginning.  Pps1Stop.tsc, line 46 added2.3.2  </p>
 <p>2010Feb17, jhaigh@aanddtech.com, added a while loop to all limit action procedures to accommodate local fault log.  If you receive a buld error due to a missing channel flgsyscallout add it to the sys.fil2.3.2</p>
 <p>2010Mar23, daniel.h.vancleve@gm.com, Updated limit action procedures and default/running limits2.3.3</p>
 <p>2010Jun04, abilliau, added chamber safety procedure to all limit action.</p>
 <p>13Sept2010, JHaigh, Added flgPps1SPControl.  When set to 0 and the setpoint goes above or below the cycler high or low imits the iTest runs a sysstop.  When set to 1 and the setpoint goes above or below the high or low limits the setpoint is trimmed to match the limits.  When set to 2 and the setpoint exceeds the limits the setpoint is ignored</p>
 <p>20Sep2010 MBarker, Upped wait for CAN comm timer in Pps1Init to 50 seconds from 30 seconds (which wasnt enough for some cyclers, see Redmine issue #212)</p>
 <p>13March2014, WLowe, Add Pps1BpTS procedure to provide seamless integration into a BpTS Application.</p>

 <h2><a id='ProcDesc'> Procedure Descriptions</a></h2>

 </body>
 </html>
 <h3><a id='Pps1BpTS.TSC'>Pps1BpTS.TSC</h3>
 <blockquote>
 <h4>Procedure Description</h4>
 <p> This procedure is used as a shell to allow the AV module to support BcTS commands
 Pps1BpTS is called from Pps1Init procedure and will run in the background with a loop delay
 of valSysScanPeriod. The AV Modes are defined with the module channel numPps1ModeOut.
 0 = Voltage
 1 = Current
 2 = Power
 3 = Standby
</p>
 <h4>Argument Description</h4>
 <p> None</p>
 <h4>Return Description</h4>
 <p> None

</p>
 </blockquote>
 <h3><a id='Pps1ContCheck.TSC'>Pps1ContCheck.TSC</h3>
 <blockquote>
 <h4>Procedure Description</h4>
 <p> This procedure is used to make sure the AV Cycler has not entered into a fault
 mode. If it enters into a fault condition then flgPps1PackErr is set. I believe 
 flgPps1PackErr has active limits that will cause a fault condition that will shut down the cycler
</p>
 <h4>Argument Description</h4>
 <p> None</p>
 <h4>Return Description</h4>
 <p> None

</p>
 </blockquote>
 <h3><a id='Pps1ErrorText.TSC'>Pps1ErrorText.TSC</h3>
 <blockquote>
 <h4>Procedure Description</h4>
 <p> This procedure is called by Pps1ContCheck and is used to determine what the 
 current problem ID value means and set it to the Packet Error virtual string channel
</p>
 <h4>Argument Description</h4>
 <p> None</p>
 <h4>Return Description</h4>
 <p> None
```

If you try to run this you will see that the menu appears at the top, but not of the information below the list appears until you hover over the menu. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Typo at line:

```
    <li><a href='#Pps1LimitActionEStop.TSC'>Pps1LimitActionEStop.TSC</a></li>
<ul>
```

it should be `</ul>` (ending tag)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/v3wKr/)

You are closing your `<html> <body>` tags and had more html code after that!

Issue lines:

```
<li id="list"><a href="#ProcDesc">Procedure Descriptions</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#Pps1BpTS.TSC'>Pps1BpTS.TSC</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Pps1ContCheck.TSC'>Pps1ContCheck.TSC</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Pps1ErrorText.TSC'>Pps1ErrorText.TSC</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Pps1Exit.TSC'>Pps1Exit.TSC</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Pps1ForceStandby.TSC'>Pps1ForceStandby.TSC</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Pps1Greet.TSC'>Pps1Greet.TSC</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Pps1HWGains.TSC'>Pps1HWGains.TSC</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Pps1Init.TSC'>Pps1Init.TSC</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Pps1LimitActionEStop.TSC'>Pps1LimitActionEStop.TSC</a></li>
        <ul>
    </li>
```

Your ul is not closed properly.

```
<h2><a id='ProcDesc'> Procedure Descriptions</a></h2>

 </body>
 </html>
 <h3><a id='Pps1BpTS.TSC'>Pps1BpTS.TSC</h3>
```

body and html tags are closed and followed by more html.